# C# Could not load file or assembly from release DLL

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll

I have a WebApplication project in ASP.Net and one Entity project (Built to DLL).

If i build DLL in Debug mode then my WebApp load assembly successfully. But when I build DLL in release mode, my WebApp could not load assembly.

Error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibs, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `Configuration manager` if the `Platform` is correct. Compare them with the `Debug` configuration. Also check if the `Build` checkbox is checked.